# How to install R and RMySQL in RedHat Linux 8?

Tags: mysql, r, linux, redhat

How do I install `R` and `RMYSQL` on `RedHat Linux 8`?

Cannot get the `epel` working. Trying to install `R` gives dependency errors.

Comment: This is probably a question that should be asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). The sister sites are usually a better fit on how to use a package manager. *"Cannot get the epel working"* and *"R gives dependency errors"* are not good problem statements. You need to provide the errors you are experiencing. My guess is, a search for the error message will provide lots of hits since installing R or MySQL has been done many times before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Followed the instructions here: https://linuxconfig.org/install-r-on-linux-redhat-8 (Assuming that you have already installed the MySQL)

1. Untar the downloaded R :

   ```
   sudo su
   tar -xzvf R-3.5.2.tar.gz
   chown -R root:root R-3.5.2/
   ```
2. Now install the following using yum:

   ```
   yum install java
   yum install xz xz-devel         
   yum group install "Development tools"
   yum install readline-devel
   yum install xz xz-devel 
   yum install pcre pcre-devel
   yum install libcurl-devel
   yum install texlive
   yum install *gfortran*
   yum install zlib*
   yum install bzip2-*
   ```
3. Now configure:

   ```
   ./configure -with-x=no
   ```
4. Make install :

   ```
   make install
   ```
5. Now to launch R from anywhere:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/where/you/want/R/to/go
   (sudo ./configure --prefix=/home/ec2-user/R-3.6.0/bin)
   ```

   That should install the R.
6. you can move R: `cp -r R-3.6.0 /usr/local/R`

After this you can install DBI:

7. Install `DBI`:

   ```
   R CMD INSTALL DBI_1.0.0.tar.gz
   ```
8. Create the mariadb repo:

   ```
   vi /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
   ```
9. Add the following in the repo file:

   ```
    [mariadb]
    name = MariaDB
    baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos6-amd64
    gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
    gpgcheck=1
   ```
10. Install mariadb

    ```
    yum install mariadb-devel
    ```
11. Get RMySQL from here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html
12. Install RMySQL:

    ```
    R CMD INSTALL RMySQL_0.10.17.tar.gz
    ```
13. Test the installation:

    ```
    R
    library(RMySQL)
    db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="userName", password="passWord", dbname="mysql", host="127.0.0.1")
    ```